# How to determine whether a Windows 10 workstation is connected to the LAN via hard-wire and/or wi-fi?

Tags: powershell

Our company uses ***many*** Microsoft Access applications in various departments and workgroups for data gathering and reporting. With more of the desktop workstations being replaced with laptops, we run into more cases where users log into an Access app while they're connected via their desktop docking stations; but then they might disconnect to go to a meeting while the app is still running. Access doesn't like that.

Different IP addresses are used for the wi-fi connections; Access needs a "solid" connection to the back-end database; etc. This is also true if the user launches an Access app while connected to the network via wi-fi alone.

What I'd like to attempt is to run a PowerShell script before launching the Access app. (The Access app front-end is located on the local drive while the back-end data is stored on the network share.) The script would check the connection status of the laptop. If it's connected via wi-fi only, then don't even allow the Access app to launch.

I've looked at Get-CimInstance Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration to see the IP addresses for the NIC and the Wi-Fi adapter... but I'm stumped as to how to "generically" check how the laptop is really connected to our LAN.

I envision a PowerShell function that returns true/false if the laptop is connected to the LAN via the hard-wire NIC. If true then go ahead and launch the Access app.

Any ideas?

Sincerely,

Steve Erbach
Manitowoc, WI

Comment: Welcome to SU. SU has rules: [How to ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask)
 So, what did you search for? What have you tried? Show your code. we're here to help with your code, but not write it for you. You just write code using the built-in cmdlets to check for the connected or disconnected state of a network interface. Checking nic state is very common, straight forward this. ['powershell check network card connection state'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+check+network+card+connection+state%27&t=h_&ia=web). Any socket open app needs a connection not and MSA thing.

Comment: Checking for LAN connection (regardless of nic) or not is just a matter of asking for DNS resolution to your LAN. This is easily discoverable via the DNS cmdlets, AD cmdlets, and PowerShell environment variable values.

Comment: Thank you for the link. It's been a while since I've posted on StackOverflow/StackExchange. I appreciate your forebearance as well as your advice!

Comment: No worries, but based on how you ask the question is could just lead to opinions. If your MSA app is a hard-coded thing, then it is what it is and only the developers can/should address that. As noted by '@Cpt.Whale' and myself, just knowing whether the nic is active or not, cannot/will solve your MSA issues dropped connection issue. Ideally, if you want better control of the MSA things, then a redesign of that MSA app(s) is required.  I.E., using a local child db which will sync/update to a Parent db on connection status, and have the MSA code directly do this.

Comment: We've discussed a disconnected operation for our MSA apps (I'm the developer). But I've only been on this job for four months and I've only begun to marshal some best practices. I appreciate your input very much.

Comment: No worries. I've been developing since the late 1970's and have spent my time with MSA and more in that time. I've done stuff like what I mentioned several times. So, it is doable but it needs to be well-planned to limit sync, so as to not step on data written by another session. You can just take the direct step in your MSA code, to check LAN state, and comply warn the user the LAN is not available, and close the app, with no PS needed. So, all self-contained. Honestly, if you are on Azure/M365, I'd look to using a containerized APP in those vs local, thus future-proofing your stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powershell, you can filter for what type of network connection with the `MediaType` property. For example:

```
$ethernet = Get-NetAdapter -Physical | 
  Where {$_.Status -eq 'Up' -and $_.MediaType -eq 802.3} 

# run the program if connected
if ($ethernet) {
  "Run program here"
}

# otherwise show the user an error message
else { 
 [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('No ethernet connection detected','Error','OK','Error')
}
```

---

It won't fix users swapping to wifi though.

Since your wireless network is on a different subnet, it's probably easier to just block connections (via firewall rules) to the Access database from wifi IP addresses

Comment: Turns out that our wireless network is spread out over several subnets; so messing with the firewalls would be very tedious. But the Get-NetAdapter is just the ticket. Much appreciated.